# Regex can't seem to quite capture decimal point

Tags: regex

I want to capture the real number that follows the characters "FM"
The regex I have does it in most situations except when there is a decimal point directly after the characters FM, e.g FM.3 it only captures the digit 3 and not the decimal point.

here's my regex

```
FM\W?(\.{0,1}\d?\.?\d?)?
```

here are the strings to test

```
MC1 FM1.2 MC2,
 FM.3,
FM 3,
FM.3,
FM 2 MC1,
FM 0.2 P1 MC1,
FM .3 ,
```

here's a demo https://regex101.com/r/ZBVpuS/2
It's much easier to see the issue at this link

Comment: Which language?

Comment: Try [`FM\W?(\.?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`](https://regex101.com/r/ZBVpuS/3)

Comment: Try [`FM\W??(\.\d+|\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`](https://regex101.com/r/ZBVpuS/4)

Comment: Is there a reason you use `\W` instead of `\s`? You might change it to `[^\w.]?`to achieve what you want.

Comment: Sebastian, thank you, no there was no reason , now that I think of it, it will only ever be a space. the \s works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/ZBVpuS/5)

```
FM\s*(\.\d+|\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

- `FM` Match this literally
- `\s*` Match any number of whitespace charactesr
- `(\.\d+|\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` Capture either of the following options into capture group 1

  - `\.\d+` Match `.` followed by one or more digits
  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match one or more digits, optionally followed by a dot and one or more digits. If you want to allow a match on a number such as `1.` where there's no digit after the decimal point, you can change `\.\d+` to `\.\d*`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `\W` which will swallow the dot (a non-word character):

```
FM\s*(\.?\d?\.?\d?)?
```

The `\s*` outside of the capture group will drop any whitespace after FM.

Comment: this worked well. I gave the solved to ctwheels as it was a slightly more comprehensive answer.